# Reactjs Unnecessary escape character: \

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hice una funciona para que me validara un campo email, esta es la función:

```
if(!fields["email"]){
  formIsValid = false;
  errors["email"] = "Ingrese un Email";
}

if(typeof fields["email"] !== "undefined"){
  let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (reg.test(fields["email"]) === false) {
    formIsValid = false;
    errors["email"] = "Ingrese un Email valido"; 
  }
  if(this.props.DataUsers.some(user => user.email.toUpperCase() === fields["email"].toUpperCase() )){            
    formIsValid = false;    
    errors["email"] = "El Email: "+fields["email"]+" se ecuentra registrado, Ingrese otro Email";
  }          
}
```

pero por consola me muestra lo siguiente:
Line 43:28:  Unnecessary escape character: .                 no-useless-escape
Line 43:44:  Unnecessary escape character: .                 no-useless-escape

a que se debe esto???

por los momentos funciona para correos locos como por ejemplo:
`examlé@correo.com example*@correo.com example-@correo.com example@correo examplecorreo.com` 
para correos de este tipo no los esta dejando pasar, por que indica que esta funcionando, pero ahora me muestra el error por consola mostrado arriba

Comment: Cuando se  trata de expresiones regulares para validar correo, no reinventes la rueda, usa [esta expresión](https://emailregex.com/) que funciona un 99.99% de las veces (según ellos mismos). Saludos